# Index and Aggregate in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to ask if any wrong with my formula below, and how to avoid duplicate text as below expected result shown?

Current result -

> Reconfirm booking made 126
> Resend Confirmation letter 2
> Request for confirmation no. 1
> Reconfirm email address in booking 0
> Reconfirm email address in booking 0

Expected result -

> Reconfirm booking made 126
> Resend Confirmation letter 2
> Request for confirmation no. 1
> Reconfirm cancellation policy 0
> Reconfirm email address in booking 0

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($G$168:$G$196,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW($G$168:$G$196)-ROW($G$168)+1)/(($G28=$H$168:$H$196)*($D$28=$F$168:$F$196)),COUNTIFS($H$168:$H$196,$G28,$F$168:$F$196,$D$28))),"")
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: try this `=IFERROR(UNIQUE(INDEX($G$168:$G$196,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW($G$168:$G$196)-ROW($G$168)+1)/(($G28=$H$168:$H$196)*($D$28=$F$168:$F$196)),COUNTIFS($H$168:$H$196,$G28,$F$168:$F$196,$D$28))))`

Comment: I have tried, but the result remain the same

=IFERROR(UNIQUE(INDEX($G$168:$G$196,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW($G$168:$G$196)-ROW($G$168)+1)/(($G31=$H$168:$H$196)*($D$28=$F$168:$F$196)),COUNTIFS($H$168:$H$196,$G31,$F$168:$F$196,$D$28)))),"")

Comment: It is much easier to help you, if you provide your data as text (make use of [Markdown Table Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables)) (read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/16578424) for an explanation)